# conjugate transpose of contraction

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, transpose

is it true, for any matrix $T \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ (with scalar product $\langle .,.\rangle$ and the norm $\left\Vert v\right\Vert = \langle v,v\rangle^{\frac{1}{2}}$), that, if $T$ is a contraction  ($\left\Vert T \right\Vert = \sup\limits_{\left\Vert v \right\Vert = 1} \left\Vert Tv\right\Vert \leq 1$), the conjugate transpose $T^*$ also is a contraction?
thanks in advance for your help

//Edit: $\langle .,.\rangle$ is supposed to be an arbitrary inner product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I prefer to denote by $A^H$ the conjugate transpose of a complex matrix $A$.
Note that

$$ \left< Tv, Tv \right> = (Tv)^{H} Tv = v^{H} T^{H} T v. $$

The matrix $T^H T$ is Hermitian and positive-semidefinite. From the equation above, we see that $T$ is contraction if and only if $T^H T$ has no eigenvalues whose norm is greater than one. Similarly, $T^H$ is a contraction if and only if $T T^H$ has no eigenvalues whose norm is greater than one. Since $T^H T$ and $T T^H$ have the same eigenvalues, the result follows. The fact that $T^H T$ and $T T^H$ have the same eigenvalues follows from example from the existence of a SVD decomposition of a matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think i was unclear in my question, i wanted $\langle .,. \rangle$ to be an arbitrary inner product. I'm sorry for that, I did not learn the English terminology...

Comment: Do you maybe know any generalization of what you already wrote or a place where i could look it up?

Comment: There are two possible ways I can understand your question. If $(V, \left< \cdot, \cdot \right>)$ is an arbitrary finite dimensional inner product and $T \colon V \rightarrow V$ is an operator then what I wrote above still holds - $T$ is a contraction if and only if $T^{*}$ is a contraction. To prove it, choose an orthonormal basis and reduce the problem to what was shown.

Comment: A different question is whether, given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and an arbitrary norm $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$, you ask whether if $A$ is contracting with respect to the norm then $A^H$ is also contracting. Then I'm sure the answer is no but I don't have time right now to provide an explicit counterexample. Note that the questions are not the same!

Comment: i wanted $(V,\langle .,. \rangle )$ to be an arbitrary finite dimensional inner product. So thanks a lot!